# How to add custom headers on sendmail

Tags: sendmail

I have a sendmail server and I'm trying to set it up to add a custom header called "Feedback-ID" to all outgoing messages in order to keep track of the messages sent from the server using Google's postmaster tools, however I've found surprisingly little documentation regarding that.

Is there any way to do it? Please note that this header must be added to all outgoing mail, including those received from remote clients that use my server as their MTA, and not only local messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of tinkering I found the solution. I added this to the end of sendmail.mc:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
HFeedback-ID: header_value
```

Comment: Where is that file?

Comment: Usually it's located in /etc/mail